# Restart Google Chrome with Javascript on the first time of installing extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am working on a project. The project is about developing a new extension for Google Chrome. Well everything works fine, but out of curiosity, I came to a question, if you could restart Chrome browser, after you installed your extension?

I have been looking around the internet and didn't get much success from it. Is there any Javascript code for it? 
I tried with those bellow, but with no success.

```
chrome.tabs.create({ 'url': 'chrome://restart'});
chrome.send('restartBrowser');
window.location = 'chrome://restart';
```

I thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try this in the console or with your actual extension?

Comment: have you tried
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'about:restart' }) 
?

Comment: Hey @putvande. Did in my actual extension.

Comment: @GiuseppeGrasso did and wasnt working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, allowing JavaScript to restart the browser would be a risk. Imagine if you open a malicious page that restarts the browser once it opens up, this would put it in an infinite loop where the browser keeps on restarting itself.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. That's the answer i was looking for.

Comment: No problem, here is a question on Quora that lists some best practices to allow your extension to work without restarting the browser: https://www.quora.com/How-can-Chrome-extensions-work-immediately-after-being-installed-without-restarting-the-browser

Comment: Thank you mate! Will look into it